# Adding FilterGroupBuilder to customs template creates error message

Tags: magento2, orders, filter

im trying to add and OR Filter to my template. So i added filtergroupbuilder to the construct. As soons as i add the lines im getting the following error message

> __construct(): Argument #8 ($filterGroupBuilder) must be of type Magento\Framework\Api\Search\FilterGroupBuilder

here is my code

```
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context$context,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository$orderRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder$searchCriteriaBuilder,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime$dateTime,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder$filterBuilder,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository$productRepository,
        RecipientStreetRepositoryInterface $recipientStreetRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\Search\FilterGroupBuilder $filterGroupBuilder, 
        RecipientStreetLoader $streetLoader,
        \Bird\SimpleExport\Helper\Data$helper,
        array $data = []

    ) {
        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
        $this->dateTime = $dateTime;
        $this->filterBuilder = $filterBuilder;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->filterGroupBuilder =$filterGroupBuilder;
```

removing the lines with filtergroupbuilder makes the template work. any idea what is wrong on it ?

Answer (score 0):

If you change the dependency of a given class, I assume you are in developer mode in your Magento system, then you need to clear the interceptor file for this class in your generated folder.

If you empty the folder `generated`, it will resolve your issue

If you are in production mode, you may compile `bin/magento setup:di:compile`

Answer (score 0):

thx for the help..
mode was not set to developer before editing the code.

> bin/magento setup:di:compile

made it work